# How to find the index of the permutation

Tags: prolog, permutation

```
% index(+List, -Idx) Predicate will get List with permutation and I want to
know index of permutation

For example: ?- index([4,1,3,2],X).
                X= 19.
```

My solution:

```
index([],0).
index([_],1).
index([X,Y],2):- Y > X.
index([H,X|T],Idx):-index([X|T],Idx+1),H > X.
```

Why is it wrong?
And how can I make incremention of Idx?

Comment: I tried to offer better approach in my answer. With your approach even if correct, if you can generate 1e9 permutations each second then you still need 4e19 seconds to find index of permutation of 26 elements (just example). But of course this is all very theoretical and not important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found cleaner version of same idea so I show the code:

```
permutation_index([X|Xs], I) :-
    prerequisite(
        (   sort([X|Xs], S),
            length([X|Xs], Len),
            length(S, Len)
        )),
    permutation_index(Xs, X, _N, _N_fac, I).

prerequisite(P) :- P.

permutation_index([], _Last, 0, 1, 0).
permutation_index([X|Xs], Prev, N, N_fac, I) :-
    permutation_index(Xs, X, N0, N_fac0, I0),
    succ(N0, N),
    N_fac is N*N_fac0,
    element_rank([X|Xs], Prev, R),
    I is I0 + R*N_fac.

element_rank([], _, 0).
element_rank([X|Xs], Y, R) :-
    element_rank(Xs, Y, R0),
    (   X @< Y
    ->  succ(R0, R)
    ;   R0 = R
    ).
```

This solution is not tail recursion because it seems that depth of recursion will not be a problem? It is easier to not do tail recursion, it needs less arguments. It works with any elements, only prerequisite is that elements are unique. No stupid unnecessary use of `foldl` or `nth0/4`! If you want you can additionally give it your own comparison function that only needs to be evaluated inside `element_rank` but this is overkill. However C++ standard library has `next_permutation` which lets you give it comparison predicate so maybe there is use case for this?

Now we can see if really it is possible to find the index of permutation of all letters of the English alphabet in reasonable time.

```
?- bagof(C, ( char_type(C, lower), C @> b, C @=< z ), Cs),
   reverse(Cs, Cs_rev),
   append(Cs_rev, [a,b], Letters),
   time( permutation_index(Letters, I) ).
% 1,103 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (98% CPU, 4226847 Lips)
Cs = [c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k|...],
Cs_rev = [z, y, x, w, v, u, t, s, r|...],
Letters = [z, y, x, w, v, u, t, s, r|...],
I = 403291461126605635583999998.
```

You can see that index is exactly 26!-2 so maybe it is correct? Below you can find original answer which has some explanation of algorithm and inadequate implementation. This implementation is not good but at least it is a bit better I hope?

---

You really want to enumerate all possible permutations? This is maybe too many in many of the cases? If you have a permutation of all the letters in the English alphabet for example you already have 26! = a very big number (403291461126605635584000000).

So maybe it is better to just calculate without enumerating? Also I don't think the library `permutation/2` has this option but you should be able to calcuate just "next permutation" lexicographically, without enumerating all permutations. Because when you say "index of permutation" this assumes that all possible permutations are in some order, but you don't say what order this is. Maybe it is lexicographical order? And the library `permutation/2` as in the other answer by @CapelliC has one annoying "feature" that it does not care if it is really a permutation or not:

```
?- permutation([1,1,1], P).
P = [1, 1, 1] ;
P = [1, 1, 1] ;
P = [1, 1, 1] ;
P = [1, 1, 1] ;
P = [1, 1, 1] ;
P = [1, 1, 1] ;
false.
```

This does not look correct to me at all. If you ask your program, "what is the index of permutation [1,1,1], should it answer "it is 1, and 2, and 3, and 4, and 5, and 6?" I am very uncomfortable with this answer.

Before you begin asking "what is the index of permutaton" first you need to ask "how are permutations ordered?" (lexicographically??) and you also need to make sure that all elements of your list are actually unique, and that they have an order, too. I will assume that if you have list of length *n* then in this list you have all integers between 1 and *n*, as in your example!!! If you have other elements (like letters) than you must make sure that they are unique and can be ordered and then you can assign them numbers between 1 and *n* but I think this is trivial so I don't want to write code for it. But it can look like this:

```
?- list_indices_len([c,b,a,x], Ns, Is, Len).
Ns = [3, 2, 1, 4],
Is = [1, 2, 3, 4],
Len = 4.
```

Do you see why? If not I can explain why this is important.

Then once you have a list like [4,1,3,2] and its length then you can use following algorithm:

```
permutation_index(P, Es, Len, I) :-
    succ(Len0, Len),
    P = [N|Ns],
    permutation_index(Ns, N, Len0, Es, 0, I).
```

This already knows the length of the permutation and the list because we made it with `list_indices_len/4`. Then now we only have to do n-1 steps and each time we multiply the 0-based index of the number in the list of remaining numbers with the factorial of the number of remaining numbers.

```
permutation_index([], _, _, _, I, I).
permutation_index([N|Ns], N0, X, Es, Acc, I) :-
    once( nth0(N_i, Es, N0, Es0) ),
    factorial_expr(X, X_fac),
    succ(X0, X),
    Acc1 is N_i*X_fac + Acc,
    permutation_index(Ns, N, X0, Es0, Acc1, I).

factorial_expr(F, E) :-
    (   F =:= 0
    ->  E = 1
    ;   F =:= 1
    ->  E = 1
    ;   F > 1
    ->  X is F,
        numlist(2, X, [N|Ns]),
        foldl(prod, Ns, N, E)
    ).

prod(X, Y, Y*X).
```

There must be better way to calculate factorial but this works?

So now I get as expected:

```
?- permutation_index([4,1,3,2], [1,2,3,4], 4, I).
I = 19.

?- permutation_index([4,3,2,1], [1,2,3,4], 4, I).
I = 23.

?- permutation_index([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], 4, I).
I = 0.

?- permutation_index([1,2,4,3], [1,2,3,4], 4, I).
I = 1.

?- permutation_index([10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,1,2], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 10, I).
I = 3628798.
```

The last one is exactly 10!-2 as expected.

If you need more explaining I can do it but it looks quite easy to understand if you can understand the logic. Or maybe I am wrong about the logic? It seems to work however.

I made test myself to see that I am not confused about the complexity of my approach so I test again with even bigger number and it looks correct.

```
?- time(permutation_index([12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,1,2], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], 12, I)).
% 466 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (99% CPU, 1498045 Lips)
I = 479001598.

?- factorial_expr(12, E), X is E - 2.
E = ... * ... * 4*5*6*7*8*9*10*11*12,
X = 479001598.
```

There are also even more efficient ways to calculate index of permutation but maybe you should read first... you can start at the beginning:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_in_computing

Comment: An highly technical answer... the code is not very accessible. Usage of nth0/4, or foldl/4 for the factorial (that has a one liner definition as `fact(X,F) :- (X>0 -> Y is X-1, fact(Y,G), F is X*G ; F = 1).`) will make hard time for the OP (that I assume is a beginner in Prolog). Also, digesting Lehmer' codes and the relation with indexing isn't exactly easy.

Comment: @CapelliC this is not lehmer's code this is less fancy but should work for any size. I do not say that this is better than your answer at all, and why do you say "highly technical" when it is quite basic arithmetic I thought :-( it is just a sum of products. I use nth0/4 and foldl just to save typing, of course your definition of factorial is better but I could not come up with it because I am not too good at Prolog.

Comment: @CapelliC I understand that it is much more accessible to just create all permutations and count them using some global variable like a normal loop I just wanted to try and see if there is more complicated way that is less accessible. Thank you for feedback it is always nice to hear what other programmers think because learning to write good code is not easy and it is easier when we know how better programmers write and read code to make it better.

Comment: Your code is pretty good - as well as the interesting answer ! The math behind is scary - at least, to me... my naive answer could be applicable in other contests, given the peculiar computational model of Prolog.

Comment: @CapelliC I now try to do cleaner coding of problem, it is not as clean as your solution and it is not very applicable but I had an itch and I scratched it well.

Comment: Yes, it's very nice ! Welcome on board !

Answer (score 2):

permutation/2 generates elements on backtracking. It's not really easy to track the index of a solution, so this is the easier way for your immediate problem:

```
?- findall(P,permutation([1,2,3,4],P),L), nth0(I,L,[4,1,3,2]).                                                                                                                                             L = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4, 3], [1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4, 2], [1, 4, 2, 3], [1, 4, 3|...], [2, 1|...], [2|...], [...|...]|...],
I = 19 ;
false.
```

*edit*

something more efficient, could use this

```
nthsol(Goal, N) :-
    State = state(0, _),
    Goal,
    arg(1, State, C),
    N is C+1,
    nb_setarg(1, State, N).
```

in this way:

```
?- nthsol(permutation([1,2,3,4],P),I),P=[4,1,3,2].
P = [4, 1, 3, 2],
I = 20 ;
false.
```

the index now it's a counter, so it's offset by 1

Comment: I think this is good answer and I give you upvote but do you not think that it can go on for a while if you give it larger list? and I am not sure what should happen if you give it a list with not unique elements, how about [1,1,1], it will give you some strange result(s). I try to write another answer to answer the questions in this comment to your answer to the original question.

Comment: nthsol/2 it's as efficient as it can be - but generally, the problem you're after can be subtle and difficult to solve, since Prolog execution can be a complex process. The first choice (using findall/3) it's meant to be used only for not-so-big results. Of course, storing all permutations just to find an index is overkill

Comment: you are probably right but maybe you can just calculate "index" directly from numbers? I finnish writing answer and I show how and you can say if you think I am wrong which is very possible naturally.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you mean... do you have an alternative answer ? we are all interested, of course...

Comment: Why not use `call_nth/2`?