# Prolog: random permutation

Tags: random, prolog, permutation, swi-prolog

I'm trying to get random permutation with prolog. But the problem is

```
?- permutation([1,2,3,4],L).
```

gives always `L = [1, 2, 3, 4]` as first answer. I could fix this by using the query

```
?- L1=[1,2,3,4], permutation(L1,L2), dif(L1,L2).
```

But this gives me always `L2 = [1, 2, 4, 3]` as first answer.

How can I get a random permutation in SWI Prolog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't `[1,2,3,4]` random enough? Looks random to me!

But I know what you mean - you want a permutation which looks [more random](https://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2019/5/236411-algorithmic-randomness/fulltext).

Why not roll your own? Just pick the next element out of an ever-shrinking "input list".

This is a bit laborious. Maybe there are more elegant ways?

```
look_random_dammit([],[]) :- !.

% note that [PickedElement|PermutedList] APPENDS "PickedElement" 
% to list being constructed. Appending or prepending does not 
% really make a difference here though:

look_random_dammit(ListRemainder,[PickedElement|PermutedList]) :- 
   ListRemainder \== [],
   length(ListRemainder,Length),
   succ(Max,Length),  
   % We are now leaving logicland and asking an oracle to give
   % use a random number. "Buckle your seatbelt Dorothy, 'cause 
   % Kansas is going bye-bye!"
   random_between(0,Max,PickedIndex), 
   nth0(PickedIndex,ListRemainder,PickedElement),
   length(Prefix,PickedIndex),
   % Constructing a remainder list is probably slow
   append([Prefix,[PickedElement],Suffix],ListRemainder) , 
   append(Prefix,Suffix,ListRemainderNext),
   look_random_dammit(ListRemainderNext,PermutedList).
```

And so:

```
?- look_random_dammit([1,2,3,4],P).
P = [2,3,1,4] ;
false.

?- look_random_dammit([],P).
P = [] ;
false.

?- look_random_dammit([1,1,1,2,2],P).
P = [2,1,1,2,1] ;
false.
```

If we also retained the information about which elements was picked in equence, we could write a predicate that "reverses the permutation" because no information was lost while creating it.

Comment: quite entertaining :)

Comment: You can index permutations. Permutations have a lexicographical order. All you need is a single random number. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60742/finding-the-n-th-lexicographic-permutation-of-a-string

Comment: After some digging I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43183189/14411997 it answers the opposite question, "what is the index of a permutation". But can it be used in the opposite direction?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
?- random_permutation([1,2,3,4], P).
P = [2, 1, 4, 3].
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I didn't know that there is already an inbuild predicate :)

Comment: This is swi prolog.

Comment: @peter.cyc Yes! The question is tagged with SWI-Prolog.

Answer (score 1):

I am just giving an alternate method.

1. Using findall to get all possible permutations.
2. Getting the length of the List containing the permutations.
3. Using random to generate a random number between 0 and the length. This will be used as an index value.
4. Using nth1 to give us a permutation on the given index.
5. ! (Cut) is used to give only one value. if you want more values then remove it.

**Example:-**

```
perm([H|T],Permutation):-
findall(A,permutation([H|T],A),List),
length(List,Length),
random(1,Length,Random),
nth1(Random,List,Permutation),!.


?- perm([1,2,3,4],Permutation).
Permutation = [1, 4, 3, 2]

?- perm([1,2,3,4],Permutation).
Permutation = [3, 1, 2, 4]

?- perm([1,2,3,4],Permutation).
Permutation = [3, 1, 4, 2]
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Unfortunately for larger lists this gets pretty slow pretty fast.